# Como gerar um pdf do gráfico gerado pelo Treant JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, gráfico

No meu sistema eu tenho um organograma gerado com base no Treant JS e eu gostaria de poder exportalo como PDF, porém explorando pela página do plug-in não encontrei nada relacionado, algúem conhece alguma maneira de isso ser feito?

Imagem do organograma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer utilizando um plug-in chamado [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), ele é muito parecido com o [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/blob/master/README.md) só que você pode fazer imagens maiores, [segue exemplo](https://codepen.io/lucassoomago/pen/XQwjXj)

```
//HTML
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>

<div id="print">
    <h1>Exemple text</h1>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab </p>
</div>
<div id="printDiv"></div>
<button id="takePrint">Take a print</button>


//JS Code
$("#takePrint").on('click',function(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#print")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
})
```